# Interactivy on server components

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma, react-server-components

Hello I am trying to make a button when its clicked it writes that the profile of that person is applied to the job listings that button is clicked and basically it gives me that I should make my page a client component because I have put an onClick.

Here is my page code:

```
import prismadb from "@/lib/prisma";
import React from "react";
import { auth } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import Delete from "@/components/delete-button";
import { Plus } from "lucide-react";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import {
  Dialog,
  DialogContent,
  DialogDescription,
  DialogFooter,
  DialogHeader,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/dialog";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { Label } from "@/components/ui/label";
import ApplyProfile from "@/app/actions/apply";
import toast, { Toaster } from "react-hot-toast";

const notify = () => toast.success("Successfully");

const CompanyJobListings = async ({
  params,
}: {
  params: { companyId: string };
}) => {
  const listings = await prismadb.jobListing.findMany({
    where: {
      companyId: params.companyId,
    },

    include: {
      appliedPeople: {
        select: {
          id: true,
          userId: true,
          fullName: true,
          email: true,
          age: true,
          src: true,
          Education: true,
          PastPosition: true,
          Skills: true,
          TechStack: true,
          Country: true,
        },
      },
    },
  });

  const company = await prismadb.company.findUnique({
    where: {
      id: params.companyId,
    },
  });
  const { userId } = auth();
  const profile = await prismadb.profile.findUnique({
    where: {
      userId: userId!,
    },
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="mt-11 mb-11 flex justify-center items-center flex-col">
        <div className="inline-flex ">
          <a
            href={`/companies/${params.companyId}`}
            className="bg-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-400 text-gray-800 font-bold py-2 px-6 rounded-l"
          >
            Company
          </a>
          <a
            href={`/companies/${params.companyId}/job-listings`}
            className="bg-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-500 text-gray-800 font-bold py-2 px-6 rounded-r"
          >
            Job-Listings
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      {listings.map(async (listing: any, index) => {
        const handleApplyClick = async () => {
          try {
            // Assuming ApplyProfile is an asynchronous function
            await ApplyProfile(profile?.id, listing.id);
            notify(); // Notify user of successful application
          } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error applying to job listing:", error);
            // Handle error appropriately
          }
        };
        return (
          <div className="m-5" key={index}>
            <div className="group mx-2 mt-10 pl-2 grid max-w-screen-md grid-cols-12 space-x-8 overflow-hidden rounded-lg border py-8 text-gray-700 shadow transition hover:shadow-lg sm:mx-auto">
              <div className=" group relative h-16 w-16 overflow-hidden rounded-full border-solid border-2 border-black">
                <a
                  suppressHydrationWarning
                  href={`/companies/${params.companyId}/job-listings/${listing.id}`}
                >
                  {" "}
                  <img
                    src={listing.companyLogoSrc}
                    alt=""
                    className="h-full w-full object-cover text-gray-700 rounded-full"
                  />
                </a>
              </div>

              <div className="col-span-11 flex flex-col pr-8 text-left sm:pl-4">
                <h3 className="text-sm text-gray-600">{listing.companyName}</h3>
                <p className="mb-3 overflow-hidden pr-7 text-lg font-semibold sm:text-xl">
                  {" " + listing.PositionName + " "}
                </p>
                <p className="overflow-hidden pr-7 text-sm">
                  {listing.PositionDescription}
                </p>

                <div className="mt-5 flex flex-col space-y-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 sm:flex-row sm:items-center sm:space-y-0 sm:space-x-2">
                  <div>
                    Experience:
                    <span className="ml-2 mr-3 rounded-full bg-green-100 px-2 py-0.5 text-green-900">
                      {" "}
                      2 Years{" "}
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    Salary:
                    <span className="ml-2 mr-3 rounded-full bg-blue-100 px-2 py-0.5 text-blue-900">
                      {listing.Salary}
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  {company?.userId === userId && (
                    <div className="max-w-full flex justify-end">
                      <div className="flex justify-center gap-3">
                        <div className="border-black border-solid border-2 flex justify-center items-center rounded-full px-5 hover:bg-slate-100 ">
                          <a
                            href={`/update-listing/${listing.id}`}
                            className=""
                          >
                            Edit
                          </a>
                        </div>
                        <Delete id={listing.id} />
                        <Dialog>
                          <DialogTrigger asChild>
                            <Button variant="outline">Applied</Button>
                          </DialogTrigger>
                          <DialogContent className="sm:max-w-[425px]">
                            <DialogHeader>
                              <DialogTitle>Edit profile</DialogTitle>
                              <DialogDescription>
                                Make changes to your profile here. Click save
                                when you're done.
                              </DialogDescription>
                            </DialogHeader>
                            <div className="grid gap-4 py-4 ">
                              <div className="grid grid-cols-1 items-center gap-4">
                                <div className=" w-full  py-8 ">
                                  <div className="flex items-center justify-between pb-6"></div>
                                  <div className="overflow-y-scroll rounded-lg border">
                                    <div className="">
                                      <table className="w-full border-black border-solid border-2">
                                        <thead>
                                          <tr className="bg-white border-black border-solid border-2 text-left text-xs font-semibold uppercase tracking-widest text-blacl">
                                            <th className="px-5 py-3">Age</th>
                                            <th className="px-5 py-3">
                                              Full Name
                                            </th>
                                            <th className="px-5 py-3">Job</th>
                                          </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody className="text-gray-700">
                                          {listing.appliedPeople.map(
                                            (person: any) => (
                                              <tr>
                                                <td className="border-b border-gray-200 bg-white px-5 py-5 text-sm">
                                                  <p className="whitespace-no-wrap">
                                                    {person.age}
                                                  </p>
                                                </td>
                                                <td className="border-b border-gray-200 bg-white px-5 py-5 text-sm">
                                                  <div className="flex items-center">
                                                    <div className="h-10 w-10 flex-shrink-0 mr-2">
                                                      <img
                                                        className="h-full w-full rounded-full "
                                                        src={person.src}
                                                        alt=""
                                                      />
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className="ml-3">
                                                      <a
                                                        href={`/profiles/${person.id}`}
                                                        className="underline text-blue-600"
                                                      >
                                                        {" "}
                                                        <p className="whitespace-no-wrap">
                                                          {person.fullName}
                                                        </p>
                                                      </a>
                                                    </div>
                                                  </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td className="border-b border-gray-200 bg-white px-5 py-5 text-sm">
                                                  <p className="whitespace-no-wrap">
                                                    {person.PastPosition}
                                                  </p>
                                                </td>
                                              </tr>
                                            )
                                          )}
                                        </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </DialogContent>
                        </Dialog>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  )}
//the button -->     {profile && (
                    <div className="border-black border-solid border-2 flex justify-center items-center rounded-full px-5 hover:bg-slate-100 ">
                      <button onClick={handleApplyClick} className="">
                        Apply
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  )}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}

      {company?.userId === userId && (
        <div>
          <div className="flex justify-center items-center">
            <a
              href="/create-listing"
              className="text-black border border-black  hover:bg-gray-200 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-full  p-6 text-center inline-flex items-center dark:border-blue-500 dark:text-blue-500 dark:hover:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-800 dark:hover:bg-blue-500"
            >
              <Plus className="text-lg" />
            </a>
          </div>
          <div className="w-full flex justify-center mt-3">
            <span className="">Make a Listing</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CompanyJobListings;
```

and my Server Action named ApplyProfile:

```
import prismadb from "@/lib/prisma";

const ApplyProfile = async (profileid: any, listingid: any) => {
  try {
    const listing = await prismadb.jobListing.findUnique({
      where: {
        id: listingid.id,
      },
    });
    const profile = await prismadb.profile.findUnique({
      where: {
        id: profileid,
      },
    });

    if (!listing || !profile) {
      console.error("Job Listing or Profile not found");
      return;
    }
    await prismadb.jobListing.update({
      where: {
        id: listingid,
      },
      data: {
        appliedPeople: {
          connect: {
            id: profileid,
          },
        },
      },
    });
    console.log(
      "Profile successfully added to applied people for the job listing."
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error applying to job listing:", error);
  }
};

export default ApplyProfile;
```

and my prisma.schema if you need it:

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

datasource db {
  provider     = "mysql"
  url          = env("DATABASE_URL")
  relationMode = "prisma"
}

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

model Profile {
  id           String   @id @default(cuid())
  userId       String   @unique
  fullName     String   @db.Text
  email        String
  age          String
  src          String
  Education    String
  PastPosition String
  Skills       String
  TechStack    String?
  AboutMe      String
  Country      String
  LinkedIn     String
  Github       String?
  Instagram    String?
  Twitter      String?
  createdAt    DateTime @default(now())

  appliedJobListings JobListing[] @relation("appliedPeople")
}

model Company {
  id                  String       @id @default(cuid())
  userId              String       @unique
  CompanyName         String
  email               String
  phoneNumber         String?
  CompanyDescription  String
  CompanyLogoSrc      String
  CompanyType         String
  CompanyBenefits     String
  CompanyAchievements String?
  CompanyMorals       String
  CompanyTeam         String
  LinkedIn            String
  GitHub              String?
  Twitter             String?
  JobListings         JobListing[]
  CompanyCreatedDate  String
  createdAt           DateTime     @default(now())

  @@index([id], name: "idx_company_id")
}

model JobListing {
  id                  String    @id @default(cuid())
  companyId           String
  companyName         String
  companyLogoSrc      String
  PositionName        String
  PositionDescription String
  OperatingPlace      String
  Salary              String
  appliedPeople       Profile[] @relation("appliedPeople")

  company Company @relation(fields: [companyId], references: [id])

  @@index([companyId], name: "idx_joblisting_companyid")
}
```

Comment: interactivity is possible only on the browser. if you add `onClikc` on the button inside the server component, who would ever be able to click on that button on the server? it does not make sense, right? if you are adding any kind of interactivity, it should be a client component